# Background-image at bottom of screen or at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have two background-images. I want them to be fixed at the bottom of screen or at the bottom of page if the info on page is too much.
I'm able to code only one of the situations - background-images are fixed to the bottom of screen or to the bottom of page(body{}).

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-image:url(images/fonskreisapuse.png), url(images/fonslabapuse.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
}
```

In the first picture the background image is fixed to the bottom of body:
http://www.bildites.lv/viewer.php?file=ivbdtsimebot29u96rs8.jpg

In this picture the background is fixed to the bottom of screen:
http://www.bildites.lv/viewer.php?file=yzrixvjqec2qe3fgu396.jpg

I scrooled the page down to see the problem if the picture is fixed to the bottom of the screen. I want to make the background-images to be fixed to the bottom of the screen if the info on the page isn't that much or the bottom of body if the info is enough for scrooling down. And I don't want the background-images to be fixed to the bottom of screen all the time because the it will mix with main content.

I have been trying to solve this problem for few days now but I can't get it to work like that.

Comment: Are you able to put the image inside a <footer>, and use Sticky Footer to get it to stay on the bottom?

Comment: hmm, that could work nice, I'll try that tomorrow and reply here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{
    min-height:100%;
    background-attachment:scroll;
    background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Example.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom left, bottom right;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
    padding-bottom:200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>sample text</p>
<script>
addContent = function(){
    var p = document.createElement('p')
    var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    var t = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent feugiat tincidunt urna at ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id mauris arcu, sit amet suscipit sem."
    var l = new Array(10)
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(l.join(t)))
    b.appendChild(p);
    return false
 }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="return addContent()">add content</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works almost perfect. Background image is not displayed in it's full height, it's cropped somehow. http://www.bildites.lv/viewer.php?file=m3fmy5r4f41222dph3e.jpg

Comment: @user1816780: dont know, i am guessing: html{background:#fff} body{background:transparent}

Comment: It worked when i added 
    background:transparent; to body. Thanks a lot. :)